# Keep back to origin position an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, rotation

I'm now implementing an `app`, for `iOS devices` so in `objective C`, and i was asking how to keep back to origin position an `UIImageView` after a rotation ?

For example, i use my `UIImageView` like this :

```
CGAffineTransform initialPosition = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
CGAffineTransform finalPosition = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Rotate animation" context: NULL];
MySuperUIImageView.transform = initialPosition;
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
MySuperUIImageView.transform = finalPosition;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But after, i made it desappear for a time, using :

```
MySuperUIImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
```

And when i re-use it, i want it to be in the first original position, with no rotation. Is it possible easily ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Very easily:

```
MySuperUIImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is. Since you're applying an affine transform to the view, you can reset all transforms applied to the view by setting its transform to [CGAffineTransformIdentity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) which applies an identity transform matrix:

> ```
> 1 - 0 - 0
> 0 - 1 - 0
> 0 - 0 - 1
> ```

```
[mySuperUIImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

Note: In Objective C, the convention is to start class names with a capital letter, and instances with a lower case.

As of iOS 4, Apple recommends using block based UIView animation. Here's an example of what I believe you're trying to attempt using updated code.

```
CGAffineTransform finalPosition = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:kNilOptions animations:^{
    [mySuperUIImageView setTransform:finalPosition];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [mySuperUIImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other one might be shorter, but thanks =)